# Why does starting Solr with multiple Zookeeper IPs fail?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I'm trying to set up 3 Solr (8.4.0) servers with a Zookeeper (3.7.0) ensemble on Windows Server 2019. Each server has one Solr instance and one Zookeeper installed. The problem I'm facing is that I'm getting an error when trying to start Solr pointing to multiple Zookeeper Ips:

**.\solr start -c -z "172.29.70.47:2181,172.29.70.48:2181"**

Console output:

**Invalid command-line option: 172.29.70.48:2181**

I have tried various combinations of this command with or without quotes, with or without ports etc but it fails every time. If I only specify one Zookeeper IP and port the command runs fine. As soon as I specify more than one IP it fails.

I've tried setting ZK_HOST in solr.in.cmd but it also fails to start. Even in the docs (https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#using-the-z-parameter-with-binsolr) it shows that configuring multiple IPs should be possible using the -z parameter.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing this is an incompatibility in how the command line arguments are passed on when starting Solr through the cmd script on Windows. You could try starting through powershell, or dig further down into the exact line that starts Solr in `solr.cmd` and see what goes wrong. It might also have been fixed in a more recent version of Solr (check the changelog - I didn't see anything indicating a change in the git log). All the examples in the `solr.cmd` script uses a single zk host as its examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this was in fact Powershell but your comment made me wonder if running this in cmd would work. I tried and to my surprise it does work fine in cmd!

Comment: I did some further testing and it turns out if using powershell I should have used single quotes around the double quotes for the IP addresses.

Comment: Add that as an answer to your own question. Good debugging job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MatsLindh I was able to figure out what the issue was. When using Powershell the double quotes need to be wrapped in single quotes so the command should look like:

**.\solr start -c -z '"172.29.70.47:2181,172.29.70.48:2181,172.29.70.49:2181"'**

Using Command Prompt in windows double quotes work as expected and the command should be:

**solr start -c -z "172.29.70.47:2181,172.29.70.48:2181,172.29.70.49:2181"**